# Select single feature from multiple types with WFS in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs

I have a WMS base and from that create a Vector Layer for selections. Then I create 3 Control.GetFeature() controls, each using WFS to select a different feature type upon clicking the map (the 'featureselect' event). Doing it this way, however, I end up with as many as 3 Features being selected, when I want a maximum of one.

Now, ideally I'd like GeoServer to pick the best (closest) feature to the mouse click, but even using Javascript in the browser, how would I detect when all the features have come in via WFS so I can test the geometries? And what would be the best way to test them? (mostly multilines and multilinestrings)

Here's the simplified code to give you the idea of what I've got now:

```
function init() {
    var mapOptions = { /* yada yada */ }
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', mapOptions);

    var wmsOptions = { /* yada yada */ }
    var wmsLayers = 'parcelshape_lin,wmain_lin,wservice_lin,buildings_pol';
    var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "Testing",
        baseUrl+"/geoserver/wms",
        { layers: wmsLayers },
        wmsOptions
    );

    var select = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Selection", {
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.Style(OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["select"])
    });

    map.addLayers([wms,select]);

    var BuildingsControl = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({
        protocol: OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer(wms, {
            url: baseUrl+"/geoserver/wfs",
            featureType: "buildings_pol"
        }),
        hover: false
    });
    BuildingsControl.events.register("featureselected", this, function(e) {
        select.addFeatures([e.feature]);
    });
    BuildingsControl.events.register("featureunselected", this, function(e) {
        select.removeFeatures([e.feature]);
    });


    var WaterMainsControl = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({
        protocol: OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer(wms, {
            url: baseUrl+"/geoserver/wfs",
            featureType: "wmain_lin"
        }),
        hover: false
    });
    WaterMainsControl.events.register("featureselected", this, function(e) {
        select.addFeatures([e.feature]);
    });
    WaterMainsControl.events.register("featureunselected", this, function(e) {
        select.removeFeatures([e.feature]);
    });

    map.addControl(BuildingsControlCtrl);
    map.addControl(WaterMainsControl);

    BuildingsControl.activate();
    WaterMainsControl.activate();
}
```

Comment: What kind of WFS request are you opening from the controls? Can you post some code?

Comment: In your Vector Layer, there is a function, `onFeatureInsert(feature)`, that is called after a feature is inserted. Maybe you could override this method to filter what features are allowed to stay in the vector layer? But, I'm not sure of the order the features are added to the layer or how you could get the mouse click to do your processing. (hence comment and not an answer)

Comment: I have also tried the way jim novak has did. I could be able to see the features info in firebug response. But when I'm trying to work on the selected features on "features selected" event, it is not even triggering that even. Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your WFS supports it (and it looks like you're using GeoServer, which does), OpenLayers can query multiple feature types in a single WFS query:

```
var featureTypes = ["parcelshape_lin", "wmain_lin", "buildings_pol"];

var allLayersControl = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({
    protocol: OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer(wms, {
        url: baseUrl + "/geoserver/wfs",
        featureType: featureTypes
    }),
    hover: false
});
```

This is exactly what I do in my OpenLayers/GeoServer installation, the only difference being that I create a `new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({ ... })` manually instead of using `fromWMSLayer`. However, it should work identically.

Just register the events on `allLayerscontrol` and the `GetFeature` control will take care of parsing the geometries and finding the best match. If you're interested in how it does that, I'd recommend taking a look at the source for the control (`GetFeature.js` in OpenLayers).

Comment: Thanks!
This works well on the first selection, but suddenly I've got a strange issue where a second GetFeature is issued differently than the first. The first has 3 of these XML elements, each with a different typename:
`<wfs:Query typeName="feature:buildings_pol" srsName="EPSG:32054">`

The second GetFeature has this:
`<wfs:Query typeName="feature:buildings_pol,wmain_lin,wservice_lin" srsName="EPSG:32054" xmlns:feature="KwuPostGIS">`

This 2nd request gives an exception from GeoServer, saying it doesn't know a 'buildings_pol,wmain_lin,wservice_lin' feature.
A bug in OpenLayers you suppose?

Comment: Yup, that's definitely an OpenLayers bug. Do you have the latest version? This would be a showstopper for my project too, so I'll try reproducing this in my environment and see if I get similar behavior.

Comment: I'm using OpenLayers-2.11, OpenLayers.js - the big 958KB one. Trying to track through the code, but it's complex. I've never debugged javascript this involved.

Comment: I'm using OpenLayers 2.11 as well (`OpenLayers.VERSION_NUMBER == "Release 2.11"`) and am not seeing this behavior. Each request always has separate <wfs:Query> elements. You know, I think I may have seen a bug report on this a while back though. I'd recommend constructing an `OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS` object manually instead of using `fromWMSLayer` and see if you still get the same behavior.

Comment: Here's a paraphrased version of how I'm doing this with GeoServer: http://pastie.org/3086214

Comment: Also, I searched the dusty corners of my memory and I think one of the keys might be to include `version: '1.1.0'` in your WFS protocol definition. This ensures you're using the latest code, instead of the 1.0 version that had some bugs.

Comment: Bravo, sir. TBH, I was using fromWMSLayer() because I couldn't figureout how featureNS functioned in the scheme of things. Apparently not much. Using the standard OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS() constructor has made this second-click glitch disappear. Thanks again for your tips, would have taken me days to work this out.